# Download files from dropbox public folder in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor, dropbox

My goal is to obtain all the images from a public Dropbox Folder in order to display and store them in an ASP.NET MVC5 project(solutions using javascript or jquery are acceptable).

Going through the dropbox documentation seems like I have to use a Dropbox account in order to instantiate DropboxClient, but since I'm using a public URL I feel like there's a way to obtain the images without having to link any account.

Should I continue searching withing the dropbox documentation or should I explore how to do it without the api of Dropbox using WebClient or any other?

Can someone point me to a simple example of how to download all the images having only the public link to the Dropbox folder?

Comment: The Dropbox "Public folder" has been retired. Do you mean a Dropbox "shared link"? If so, this help article should be helpful: https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download You can download the raw file content that way, just using a standard HTPS client, without using a `DropboxClient`.

Comment: Thanks for your input Greg, it helped me to shape what i want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Greg, i can download all the contents following the instructions on this link.  https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download